# Why can't I delete my post which has got an answer?

Tags: support

I got downvotes on a post and want to delete it but someone has already answered the question and I am unable to delete it now.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The system won't allow you to delete a question once someone else has answered it, since then you'd be deleting their work, too. You can flag it for a moderator to look at and they can decide whether to close it. My suggestion, though, is for you to make edits to improve the question so that it stops attracting downvotes. This way, both the question and the answer stick around as a reference for others who come along with the same question.